# Is there a general tag for questions related to the container architecture?

Tags: support, tags

Is there any tag for questions generally related to *the container architecture*?

[image]

- The tag [containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/containers) (or [container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/container)) refers to a different thing; it is irrelevant. **And it is often misused to mean the container architecture.**
- There’s [docker-container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-container), but this is specific to Docker. Docker is not the only *container runtime*.
- [container-runtime-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/container-runtime-interface), but this is specific to Kubernetes.

Comment: Looks like there's [[tag:linux-containers]] and [[tag:windows-container]] respectively (mind the plurality difference), which are for this, divided by OS. Their wikis are near identical: "*[Linux/ Windows] containers are an operating system-level virtualization method for running multiple isolated [Linux/ Windows] systems (containers) on a single control host.*"

Comment: @zcoop98 Do you think there should be an OS-agnostic one?

Comment: I can certainly see the usefulness in theory, and if you see existing questions that could directly benefit then I say definitely. If a new platform-agnostic container tag would genuinely help prevent the misuse of [[tag:container]], then I'd say double yes.

Answer (score 9):

We don't need a generic container tag, not even a per-OS tag. Containers are different implementations of para-virtualization and none is compatible with each other. [LXC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC) containers aren't compatible with [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29), nor with [Kubernetes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubernetes), nor with [Xen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xen)*, etc.

If there are programming questions about these, they are usually about using each API of the [dom0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xen#Software_architecture), controller, or [orchestration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchestration_%28computing%29). If you have a question about managing containers, these are very unlikely to be on topic for SO.