# Ambiguous tag [containers]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/containers) tag description says:

> A container is a class, a data structure, or an abstract data type whose instances are collections of other objects. Containers typically make use of generics or templates so that a wide variety of objects can be added.

Currently there are 8,968 questions with this tag and this use case seems rare. I'm not familiar with Stack Overflow tag moderation guidelines, but perhaps this one is worth cleaning up?

Comment: This *does* sound like it could be easily confused with things like Docker Containers or CSS Container Queries.

Comment: There's a number of docker questions on there, along with other uses of virtual containers. Definitely worth cleaning up

Comment: @NatRiddle Who is asking questions about CSS Container Queries? First, those should be tagged something like [tag:css-container-queries]. Second, those don't work in any browser yet so no one should asking questions about them.

Comment: @TylerH That's technically wrong. [It's "supported"](https://caniuse.com/css-container-queries) by Chromium on an opt-in basis, and there might be various beta/nightly versions of other browsers supporting it without them being listed on caniuse. Not that it really matters, but there's always early adopters

Comment: @Zoe "support" is not the same as "can enable an experimental proto-implementation of a proposed idea behind browser flags on one browser". CSS Container Queries are just a suggestion right now in the W3C working group (and not even the only final candidate for the problem they seek to solve). No browser can even technically support them yet because, technically, they aren't a feature yet, just an idea proposed by David Baron.

Comment: If CSS Container Queries ever do gain actual support, then we'll need room on the site for it. Either way, I was only suggesting potential meanings, let's not get carried away.

Comment: Is there a clear primary usage for this tag, of the many topics it's apparently used for? It looks like over a third are tagged [[tag:docker]] via my [cross-tag usage query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398286/cross-tag-tag-usage-breakdown?TagName=containers). Second place is [[tag:c++]], with a little less than 1 in 5 [[tag:containers]] questions tagged with that one.

Comment: @zcoop98 no, there isn't. Someone was arguing that it should be about VM's containers, which also doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 12):

Literally copy-n-pasting the same answer [from previous discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407811/792066)

> We don't need a generic container tag, not even a per-OS tag. Containers are different implementations of para-virtualization and none is compatible with each other. LXC containers aren't compatible with Docker, nor with Kubernetes, nor with Xen*, etc.
>
> If there are programming questions about these, they are usually about using each API of the dom0/controller/orchestation. If you have a question about managing containers, these are very unlikely to be on topic for SO.

And the same applies to this case. We don't need a generic container tag for any framework/library/language either. Just let it burn.

Comment: Most of the C++ questions with the "container"-tag is about "container-data-type" (also known as collections in other languages) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/container-data-type

Comment: @Jonas what would be the problem with tagging those [c++]?